# How to check the first condition for a random variable involving integration to be the conditional expectation

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I find an exercise [here(Example 5)](https://www.math.purdue.edu/%7Estindel/teaching/ma539/cdt-expectation-2.pdf). Let $(X,Y)$ be a couple of real random variables with density $f:\mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R_+}$. Assume that for all $y$, the marginal density function at $Y=y$ is always positive. Let $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function such that $g(X)\in L^1(\Omega)$. Show that $$E[g(X)|Y]=h(Y)$$ with $$h(y)=\frac{\int_\mathbb{R}g(x) f(x,y) \mathrm{d}x}{\int_\mathbb{R}f(x,y) \mathrm{d}x}$$

We need to prove two things. First, check that $h(Y)$ is measurable w.r.t. $\sigma(Y)$. Second, show that for any set $A\in \sigma(Y)$, it holds that $E[h(Y)1_A]=E[g(X)1_A]$. I understand the proof of the second step, but have no idea how to prove the first step. It suffices to show that $h(y)$ is Borel measurable. However, $h(y)$ contains an integral, which I am not able to evaluate.

Any comments or ideas are welcome.

**Remark** The second step is proved using the joint density function: For any $A\in \sigma(Y)$, we can find a borel set $B$ such that $1_A=1_B(Y)$. Then $$
E[h(Y)1_A]=E[h(Y)1_B(Y)]
=\int_B\int_\mathbb{R} h(y)f(x,y) \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y=\int_B \mathrm{d}y\int_\mathbb{R} g(z)f(z,y) \mathrm{d}z =E[g(X)1_B(Y)]  
$$

Comment: That $h$ is a Borel function follows from Fubini's theorem.

Comment: Could you clarify it more clearly? How can it be connected to the Fubini's theorem?

Comment: It should be clear to you that $h$ is a function of $Y$. i,e, $h$ is determined by what values $Y(\omega)$ takes. And then, you are just looking at the integral over the first coordinate of a Borel measurable function on $\Bbb{R}^{2}$ which is measurable. Thus $h$ is a measurable function of $Y$, which is what it means to be $\sigma(Y)$ measurable.

Comment: Well Fubini's theorem says that if $F:X\times Y\to\mathbb R$ is in $\mathcal L^1(\mu\otimes\nu)$, then $\int_{X\times Y}F(x,y)\,\mu\otimes\nu(dx,dy)=\int_Y\int_X F(x,y)\mu(dx)\nu(dy)$, and a requirement for this to make sense is of course that the function $y\mapsto\int_X F(x,y)\mu(dx)$ is measurable, and this is a part of the theorem.